# I needed an algorithm to follow to find the minimum dominant set

Tags: c#, algorithm, graph-theory

You are provided with a graph represented through a bool matrix. For example:

```
Input:
bool[,] dungeons2 = {{F, F, T, F, F},    
                  {F, F, T, F, F},    
                  {T, T, F, T, T},     
                  {F, F, T, F, F},   
                  {F, F, T, F, F}}; 
Output:[2]
```

Example2:

```
Input: 
bool[,] dungeons1 = 
{{F, T, F, F, F, F ,F},
 {T, F, T, F, F, T ,F}, 
 {F, T, F, T, F, T,F }, 
 {F, F, T, F, T, F ,T}, 
 {F , F, F, T, F, F,T }, 
 {F, T, T, F, F, F,F }, 
 {F, F ,F, T, T, F,F}};

Output:[1,3]
```

We want to find the minimum set of vertices that is necessary to choose to guarantee that every vertex of the graph is either in the set or is a neighbor of some vertex of the graph.
I have read that it solves the minimum dominant set algorithm. In addition, I have tried to find the set of cut vertices but sometimes the cut vertices do not guarantee that it is minimum, in addition I have tried to find a dominant set by removing the vertices that have the most neighbors and removing all their neighbors from the graph. but it does not guarantee that it is minimum, how can I proceed?

Note :graph[i,j] = true represent that vertices i and j are connected .no vertex is connected to itself

Comment: Are you asking us to do your homework?

Comment: The dominating set problem is NP-Complete, so there isn't a polynomial time algorithm to find exact solutions. If your inputs are relatively small, however, iterating over the 2^n possible solutions should be feasible. (Start with *n choose 1*, then *n choose 2*, *n choose 3*...)

Comment: " is a neighbor of some vertex of the graph"  Are you sure?  Maybe you mean "is a neighbor of some vertex in the set"?

Comment: No response after many hours.  If you cannot be bothered to respond, then delete the question.